# Reachability to a WIFI with swift language

Tags: ios, swift, connection, wifi, reachability

I'm trying to get the name of the WIFI where I am connected. Is it possible to know it in Swift code without bridging to Objective-C? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
CWInterface(interfaceName: nil).ssid()
```

By passing 'nil' as an interface, you get the currently connected wifi.